# Проблема при передаче данных через TCP протокол между ПК, подключенными к Wi-Fi

Tags: c#, winforms, wifi, tcp, передача-данных

Пытаюсь в *C#* передавать данные с помощью *сокетов* и протокола *TCP* через интернет методом *peer-to-peer* (без сервера).

Проблема заключается в том, что не удается передать данные от компьютера 1, подключенного проводным способом (*Ethernet*), к компьютеру 2, подключенного беспроводным способом (*Wi-Fi*).

Использовал все возможные *IP*-адреса компьютера 2 для передачи ему данных (внутренний и даже внешний) и при этом использовал только незанятые порты, но никакого результата это не дало. Разве что сообщение на компьютере 1:

> Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера [адрес]:[порт]

Я проверял работоспособность кода при передаче данных между компьютерами, подключенными оба к *Ethernet*, все работало просто на "ура". Поэтому, скорее всего, проблема с *IP*-адресами, но я так и не пойму в чем.

На всякий случай даю вам часть кода:

```
//--- При запуске формы на комп. 2
Data_Thread = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Data_Receiver));
Data_Thread.Start();

//--- Передача данных от комп. 1
Data_Thread.Start();
string MessageText = Message.Text; // берется с Textbox-a Message передаваемые данные
Byte[] SendBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MessageText);
IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(text_IP.Text), 7000); // берется с Textbox-a text_IP адрес другого компьютера
Socket Connector = new Socket(EndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Connector.Connect(EndPoint);
Connector.Send(SendBytes);
Connector.Close();

//--- Принятие данных на комп. 2
Listen_Data = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7000);
Listen_Data.Start();
//Пришло сообщение
Socket ReceiveSocket = Listen_Data.AcceptSocket();
Byte[] Receive = new Byte[256];
//Читать сообщение будем в поток
using (MemoryStream MessageR = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Количество считанных байт
    Int32 ReceivedBytes;
    do
    {//Собственно читаем
        ReceivedBytes = ReceiveSocket.Receive(Receive, Receive.Length, 0);
        //и записываем в поток
        MessageR.Write(Receive, 0, ReceivedBytes);
        //Читаем до тех пор, пока в очереди не останется данных
    } while (ReceiveSocket.Available > 0);
}
```

Comment: некоторые роутеры любят изолировать wifi клиентов от остальной части сети, а то и от других wifi клиентов. И если в интернет-кафе это удобно, то дома - нет. Ищите в настройках роутера.

Comment: пожалуйста, сформулируйте поточнее, в чём именно состоит ваш вопрос. внести исправления можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Компы в принципе не видят друг друга? Ни ping, ни telnet?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего на твоем ВайФай роутере стоит скрытый Файрволл. Отключи его.
Он может затыкать порты.
Зайди на роутер по http:// и выключи Файрволл

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения.